# What are the range of legal limits on guests in a rental apartment

Tags: rental-property

let's say I rent an apartment long term 1-2yrs

what restrictions can a landlord place in me having guests?

I'm curious about the range for example my impression is the landlord and claim a long term guess is a tennent and needs to be added to the lease. Is that true? What the minimum limit? I can imagine a landlord saying in the rental agreement that a guest staying 8 weeks or longer is a tennent. How about 2 weeks? 2 days? 2 hours?

i'd guess this is different by state but what is the range. Do some state allow zero guests vs other set some specific legal minimum time before a guest becomes a tennent ?

PS: this question is not about AirBnB. Rather it's just wondering what control a landlord can place on a long term guest. Like say my long distance girlfriend visits for 4 months

Comment: Did you check your lease?  I had one that says anyone saying more than 10 days and two weekends in a given month would be considered a tenant.  But four months, more than 25% of the year,  seems unreasonable to be considered a guest.

Comment: I'm asking what is legal to put in the lease. I believe (though of course I'm not a lawyer) that the lease can't say "no guests". Plenty of people have lovers stay 4,6,12 months without changing their lease. So, what's the law say? That is my question. Plently of leases don't follow the actual law and put in restrictions that aren't actually legal. It would seem like there must be some ranges the law in various states have come up with like it's reasonable to have your mom visit for 4 weeks but not reasonable to put up your homeless friend for a year.

Comment: Where are you? I can answer this question for New York City, but I'm not sure how much of the regulation there is also in effect for the rest of the state, and I am certain that none of it applies in any other state or territory of the US, let alone in any other country.  @Andy in NYC a residential tenant who is the sole lessee has a right to have an unrelated roommate without modifying the lease. Any lease provision to the contrary would be void.

Comment: just looking for a range. NYC sound like no limit? Can you have 2 roommates? 3? 12? Does any state allow a landlord to place limits? time limits? people limits? that's what I'm looking for. The range of limits

Comment: That people do it without modifying their lease doesn't mean they are not in violation of their lease.  And what's legal it's going to vary alot state to state and maybe city by city.

Comment: @phoog Well my lease was in PA.  Not sure if or was legal there or not, but i know there was such a clause.

Comment: This question is similar to "what are the ranges of legal drinking age in the USA", answer (it was 18 to 21 in the past but now all states are 21) or "what is the range of ages of consent in the USA", answer (16 to 18). The answer here might be slightly more complicated but not much. It seems entirely unreasonable to allow no guests period, no sister or mom visiting for the weekend. It's possible some states allow this restriction tho. No idea hence the question. What's the ranges.